# class uses a non-entity [class java.lang.Boolean] in HashMap?

Tags: java, jpa, hashmap

I want to have the following field in my Presentation class (JPA entity):

```
private HashMap<User, Boolean> users = new HashMap();
```

but when I run our databasetest (fill db with testdata), I get the following errormessage:

```
[class domein.Presentation] uses a non-entity [class java.lang.Boolean]
 as target entity in the relationship attribute [field users].
```

I have tried using the annotations `@ElementCollection` and `@BasicMap` but they both don't work. My current solution is to make a new Entity class `MyBoolean`, but that is ugly code. How can I do this?

Comment: Yes, it is the Boolean that JPA has problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA doesn't provide for a Map with the key being an Entity and the value being a non-Entity. JDO supports that FWIW.

Comment: Well I'm mapping it manually now, by making a new class "UserPresentation" and in there 1 user, 1 presentation and my boolean.